# Трёхмерный массив с пропусками (C++, map)

Tags: c++, unordered-map

У меня есть трёхмерный массив с вот таким объявлением:

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, T*>>> &ll=data[0];
```

Как мне в нём создать, удалить, проверить наличие, пройтись по всему массиву?
Я знаю пару способов, но они по 100 строк и очень неэффективны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Создать и/или присвоить элемент по индексам `[i][j][k]` легко: простое обращение через операторы `[]` вам все само прекрасно создаст

  ```
  ll[i][j][k] = /* какое-то значение вашего типа `T *` */;
  ```
- Проверить наличие по индексам `[i][j][k]` тоже легко, но более громоздко:

  ```
  if (auto iti = ll.find(i); iti != ll.end())
    if (auto itj = iti->second.find(j); itj != iti->second.end())
      if (auto itk = itj->second.find(k); itk != itj->second.end())
        /* Нашлось! Значение равно `itk->second` */;
  ```
- Пройти по всем тоже несложно:

  ```
  for (const auto &pi : ll)
    for (const auto &pj : pi.second)
      for (const auto &pk : pj.second)
        /* Элемент `pk.second` с индексами [pi.first][pj.first][pk.first] */;
  ```
- Удалить по индексам `[i][j][k]`: зависит от того, насколько рьяно вы хотите удалить все на данный момент не нужное, т.е. пустые подмапы. Самый агрессивно удаляющий все вариант, с проверкой существования удаляемого элемента:

  ```
  if (auto iti = ll.find(i); iti != ll.end())
    if (auto itj = iti->second.find(j); itj != iti->second.end())
      if (auto itk = itj->second.find(k); itk != itj->second.end())
      {
        /* Удаляем, если нужно, сам `T`, т.е. `itk->second` */

        itj->second.erase(itk);
        if (itj->second.empty())
        {
          iti->second.erase(itj);
          if (iti->second.empty())
            ll.erase(iti);
        }
      }
  ```

  Если же вы абсолютно уверены в существовании элемента `[i][j][k]`, ваш `T` не требует удаления и вы не хотите заниматься ранним удалением пустых подмапов, то все можно сделать в одну строчку

  ```
  ll.find(i)->second.find(j)->second.erase(k);
  ```

---

Однако возможно, что вместо такого "трехэтажного" `unordered_map` вам бы лучше подошел обычный "одноэтажный" `unordered_map`, в котором в качестве ключа выступала бы тройка чисел `(i, j, k)` (`std::tuple`). Это многое бы упростило.

Comment: Такая проверка не хочет работать(да и выглядит странно). Использовать одну мапу не получается. Уже 3 попытка создать достаточно быстрое хранение и обработку этого массива.

Comment: @Никита Самоуков: Что такое "не хочет работать"? Вот все работает: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebdc683d1c160575

Comment: c++17 a у меня 11 наверно ; в if не ест

Comment: @Никита Самоуков: Ну тогда придется элементарным образом переписать эти if-ы в стиле С++11, т.е. просто вынести объявления переменных и поставить их перед их if-ами.

Comment: Доделал наконец этот четырёхмерный массив вроде работает. Только удаление в цикле не хочет работать крашится какой-то итератор.